# Does any one know how to solve this integral numerically?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am a new user and I haven't done numerical integration like the one I have here, in the past.I want to calculate this integral numerically. but it will diverge due to the zero in denominator causing by `x = ω`. Does any body know how to approach such problems?

```
  A=1;
  a = 4;
b = 2;
c = 1;
ω = 10000;
NIntegrate[
  Log[A Exp[(-a (x - c)^2)/(2 b^2)] Exp[(a (ω - c)^2)/(2 b^2)]]/((x)^2 - ω^2)
, {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {(x)^2 - ω^2 == 0}]
```

Comment: Well, to compute it numerically, you'll have to specify numerical values for omega, a, b, c, and A. But it looks you might be interested in a principal value integral, in which case you maybe want to do some complex contour integration>

Comment: @march my problem is omega, which is changing from zero to infinity, and at some point it will have the same value as omega' which will cause it to converge. Do you know how to give omega values so that the integral doesn't converge? suppose a=b=c=1

Comment: Note `ω'` is `Derivative[1][ω]`, not an independent variable.

Comment: @Michael E2, Thank you

Comment: The integrand approaches a constant as `x->Infinitiy` so this diverges (unrelated to the zero denominator)

Comment: What is `A` ? (You realize mathematica is case sensitive..) If `A=1` there is no singularity, but as said it diverges anyway.

Comment: @goerge2079 Is there anyway to make it converge?

Comment: you can make it converge by changing the problem, eg have a finite bound.